# JavaMail Exception : STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:OutboundSpamException

Tags: android, outlook, smtp, jakarta-mail

I used java mail API to send email from Gmail, Hotmail and Outlook account. It worked well with Gmail and Hotmail, **but not work on Outlook** .

**Code for Outlook Sender Class**

```
public class OutlookSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {


    private String mailhost = "smtp-mail.outlook.com";
    private String user;
    private String password;
    private Session session;

    static {
        Security.addProvider(new JSSEProvider());
    }

    public OutlookSender(String user, String password) {
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;


        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");


        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
        session.setDebug(true);
    }

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
    }

    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body,
                                      String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
        message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setDataHandler(handler);

        if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0){
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));

        } else{
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));

        }
        message.saveChanges();

        //Transport trans = session.getTransport("smtp");
        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect(mailhost, user, password);
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
    }
}
```

**Code to send email :**

```
OutlookSender sender = new OutlookSender("abc@outlook.com", "password");
sender.sendMail("Hello Text", "Body Text Sample", "abc@outlook.com", "zxy@gmail.com");
```

**After sending, I got a exception from logcat with content :**

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: 554-554 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:OutboundSpamException; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message WASCL UserAction verdict is not None. Actual verdict is HipSend...
```

Please help explain the reason of exception and how to fix this issue. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like outlook.com thinks you're sending spam.  What does the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show?

Comment: @BillShannon, it show nothing.

Comment: If it shows nothing, you're not doing it right.

Answer (score 4):

this is outlook security, It need using web to login.
you can also check this mail to unlock your account.

---

Hello xxxxx,
To continue sending messages, please **sign in** and validate your Outlook.com account.
This helps us stop automated programs from sending junk email.
Thanks for your help and patience!
The Outlook.com Team

Comment: just to clarify this answer, check the inbox on the account you are trying to use for an email from the outlook team with steps needed to verify the account